# Updating a lookup type field

Tags: lookup-column

I have 2 lookup fields on a form. I have the following code and it's populating the 2 lookup fields. However, when I click on save button it complaints about field is required but I see both are populated with the correct value. Any idea?

```
NWF$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = NWF$('#' + vartestlookupID);
    //alert("Selected Name");
    obj.change(function () {

    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("EmployeeData");
    var listItem = oList.getItemById(this.value);
    clientContext.load(listItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    document.getElementById(varFirstNameID).value = listItem.get_item('FirstName');
    document.getElementById(varLastNameID).value = listItem.get_item('LastName');
    document.getElementById(DepartmentName).value=listItem.get_item('DepartmentName').get_lookupId();
    document.getElementById(WorkLocation).value=listItem.get_item('WorkLocation').get_lookupId();   
    document.getElementById(Supervisor).value = listItem.get_item('Supervisor');        
    }, function () {        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added 2 lines code right after setting each lookup field on the form.

```
NWF$("input[id='" + DepartmentName + "']").val(NWF$("#" + DepartmentName + " option:selected").val());
```

and

```
NWF$("input[id='" + WorkLocation + "']").val(NWF$("#" + WorkLocation + " option:selected").val());
```